# When do we use haven't had, hadn't had, and didn't have?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, past-tense, perfect-aspect

For example:
I haven't had my breakfast.
I hadn't had my breakfast.
I didn't have my breakfast.

Could you clarify if the abovementioned sentences are grammatically correct, and if yes, then what are their differences and how do we know which sentence to use?

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Nandita. We expect people to do a little research about their questions. In this case, you could look at the differences between the three tenses in these sentences: present perfect, past perfect and past simple. If, after your research, you are still unclear about something, please edit your question to provide details of your research, and specify what exactly you still don't understand.

Comment: I haven't had my breakfast yet [this morning]. I hadn't had my breakfast when I got your phone call yesterday morning. Because I overslept, I didn't have my breakfast until 10 p.m.

Comment: Hi Kate. Thank you making the distinctions. Could you please clarify if the two sentences "I haven't had my breakfast yet" and "I didn't have my breakfast yet" can be used interchangeably? In other words, can we use the adverb yet with the 'do' verb?